# Sizing a motor starter

Tags: motor

[image: Motor plate, 2hp, 3 phase, 7amp]

That is the motor.

Looks like the old version of a new Baldor M3558 2HP 3phase motor.

I plan to run a 230v 3phase line to the motor, but I need a starter.

This starter on Grainger looks promising:
https://www.grainger.com/product/SQUARE-D-Magnetic-Motor-Starter-19YA92

But my motor specs are 7A and 2HP

...and that starter, which is the closest I can find, is 18A and 3HP.

Is it OK to supply that extra 1HP? Is the 18A in the starter to cover for starting voltage?

Comment: Given the price of that starter, I'd take a look at a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive) and ask if it's a possible alternative.

Comment: Isn't the 3-phase version of 230V single phases ~400V, in which case it'd be into its 3.5A mode, correct?

Comment: Is that how it works? I thought it was 2hp * 750 watts = 1500 watts / 230 volts = 6.5A

Answer (score 1):

When choosing a relay or starter you need

- Contact voltage rating >= supply voltage, 230 V in your case.
- Contact current rating >= current drawn by the load. This may be considerably more than the steady running current.

The start won't 'supply' that current in the sense of forcing it into the motor. If, on the other hand, the motor draws or 'calls for' that current you know that the starter is capable of handling it.

Since it is a starter, the manufacturers will have taken the starting surge into consideration. If it's capable of starting a 3 HP motor it will be fine on a 2 HP.

Make sure you've got the right coil voltage for your control circuit.

Comment: You need to make sure the overload relay can be set for 2 Hp. Also note that the starter you linked has a 240 volt coil.

Comment: I believe this starter comes with a D3 "thermal unit" or the overload relay as stated by Charles Cowie.  Grainger doesn't say anything about the thermal unit. Other web sites show D3 as included.  Your motor will likely need other thermal unit.  Just noticed that Grainger says the starter comes without overload unit.

Comment: Elsewhere, Grainger shows  the OL relay is included. The footnote may mean the heaters for the OL relay are sold separately. You may find a lower price elsewhere if you want to buy on the internet from someone not known as well as Grainger.

Comment: Here is the heater. You need three for a 3-phase motor.https://www.grainger.com/product/SQUARE-D-Thermal-Unit-WP46104/_/N-/Ntt-overload+relay+heaters?nls=3&ssf=3&sst=subset&s_pp=false&picUrl=//static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/5B626_AS01?$smthumb$#nav=%2Fproduct%2FSQUARE-D-Thermal-Unit-WP46104%2F_%2FN-qlaZ1yzti5aZ1z0js52%2FNtt-overload%2Brelay%2Bheaters%3FR%3D5B661%26_%3D1454198982022%26nls%3D3%26picUrl%3D%252F%252Fstatic.grainger.com%252Frp%252Fs%252Fis%252Fimage%252FGrainger%252F5B626_AS01%253F%2524smthumb%2524%26s_pp%3Dfalse%26ssf%3D3%26sst%3Dsubset

Comment: @Charles: Wrap up all of that in a separate answer and get the credit as this is your area of expertise. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: I am content to let this be a team effort. Note that Brian Drummond pointed out that a VFD would be less expensive. That is my real area of expertise, but I would have to say that a VFD is less rugged and reliable and costs 4 or 5 percent in extra energy usage if you can't save energy by reducing speed.

Comment: How do I test for the contact current rating?

Comment: The VFDs on Grainger look to be anywhere from 3 to 6x the cost of the Starter. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have to test. The manufacturer says it's good for 3 HP. They have to stand over that specification.